# How to capture multiple lines of text starting at a certain position on each line with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I need to capture multiple lines of text starting at a certain position on each line with regular expression. Basically, I need to skip a tab, a two part word `Account Name` and two tabs but capture the remaining of the text. The format of the line of text which I'm trying to process is similar to following.

> `TAB`Account Name:`TABTAB`username 12/3/2012 8:25:52 PM

I've used

```
(?<=Account Name:).*
```

regex pattern to process the text lines and had a limited success by skipping first tab and the two part word. However, I couldn't skip the second tabs. I ended up with the following.

> `TABTAB`username 12/3/2012 8:25:52 PM

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: If you're reading each line individually, couldn't you just take a substring of each line instead of using a regex? Something like `yourString.Substring(yourString.IndexOf("\t\t") + 2);` would remove everything up until `username`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the tabs to the lookbehind:

```
@"(?<=Account Name:\t\t).*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that TAB TAB only occurs once per line:

```
@"\t\t(.*)$"
```